# why does git repository open submodule

Tags: git, git-extensions

I have started using git (2.39.1) and git extension (4.0.2) on windows machine.
When I create a new repository it is created under submodules  - why is that? and how can I avoid it. I don't expect and submodules to be part of my repository

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you started a repository on E: ?

Comment: No I haven't....